# Is it possible to get any child component under mouseX,mouseY in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I was wondering if a `Window`, for example ,has some child elements. Would it be possible to get which child is under its `MouseArea`'s current x and y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy to solve this problem is to convert the coordinate obtained by the mouse to global coordinates using the method `mapToGlobal()`, then use the method `mapFromGlobal()` to convert those global coordinates to local for each Item, and finally use `contains()` to verify if the point is inside the Item. To obtain the children you must use the `children()` method.

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    function itemsFromGlobalPosition(root, globalPos){
        var items = []
        for(var i in root.children){
            var children = root.children[i]
            var localpos = children.mapFromGlobal(globalPos.x, globalPos.y)
            if(children.contains(localpos)){
                items.push(children)
            }
            items = items.concat(itemsFromGlobalPosition(children, globalPos))
        }
        return items;
    }


    MouseArea{
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var results = itemsFromGlobalPosition(window.contentItem, ma.mapToGlobal(mouseX, mouseY))
            console.log("results: ", results)
        }
    }

     ...

}
```

Comment: if not need get the child recursively, can use `window.contentItem.childAt(mouseX, mouseY)`.

Comment: seems like `items +=` is concatenating strings though. I'll try this out

Comment: how do I get last item for example? if I do `results[results.length-1]` I will get ")"

Comment: but I was expecting "QQuickRectangle(0x282db10)" I only got the ")" which is the last char in the above pointer.toString() if I wanna give it a name

Comment: thanks for looking into it again and editing your answer :)

Comment: @Jiu thanks a lot for your answer as well. that helped me a lot in something else :)